Problem opening a native app from a web app
I have encountered a problem in which im trying to open a native app from a the browser and sometimes it doesn't work.
The web app is in react and what happens there is i make a request to a third-party server to get some link that looks like this: https://somelink.com
When i get the response with the link i redirect the user to that link with window.open().
The link is from a third-party provider which has a website and a native app. In theory the link should open the app if it is installed and if not it should open the the website.
In practice sometimes it open the app and sometimes not.
I have noticed that it always works in IOS and it always works from the chrome browser in android. The problem is with the native browser in different android devices, in which sometimes it works and sometimes not, with no apparent logic to it.
So my questions are:

Has anyone else experienced this issue and has a solution?
Are there any conditions in which the browser wont let me open a native app?

In the pursuit of a solution i was introduce to the concept of intent. Im not sure exactly what it does but i think im using it correctly. What im doing is taking a link like this:
https://somelink.com
and turning it into this:
intent://somelink.com#Intent;scheme=https;package=${packageName);end
It still doesn't work. Am i using intent correctly?

"Are there any conditions in which the browser wont let me open a native app?" -- there is no requirement for a browser (or any other app) to honor app links. Some browsers have that disabled by default and require the user to opt into launching apps.
